# How to index nested list?

Tags: c#, list

I am having a real problem iterating a `list<list<object>>` and would like to ask anybody for their insight.

[image: http://i44.tinypic.com/wlqcfn.jpg]

as you can see I have a `list<list<object>> posCheckOptions` which contains 32 lists and each list contains x amount of objects, i.e 348 for 0, 325 for 1 etc.

for example, in this list of 348 there are duplicate elements which I would like to remove. in duplicate I mean, the name of the stock could be the same so, if I have say, VODAFONE 4 times, I would like to add the qty of shares from each one to the first time Vodafone is spotted and delete the duplicates.

```
for(int k = 0; k<posCheckOptions.Count; k++)
{

int l = 0;
int m = 1;

while (l != m) 
{


    foreach(var x in posCheckOptions[k][l].name)
    {

         if(posCheckOptions[k][l].date != posCheckOptions[k][m].date 
            && posCheckOptions[k][l].strike != posCheckOptions[k][m].strike 
             && posCheckOptions[k][l].callPut != posCheckOptions[k][m].callPut)

               {
                    m++;
               }

               else
               {

           posCheckOptions[k][l].size = posCheckOptions[k][l].size + posheckOptions[k][m].size;

                                posCheckOptions[k].RemoveAt(m);

                                m--;

                }



                }

                    l++; m = l;
     }
}
```

What I am trying to code, well at least the idea is, I start from posCheckOptions[0][0] and compare elements `posCheckOptions[0][0].date` to `posCheckOptions[0][1].date` (i compare 4 fields) (`poscheckOptions` is a list whos type T is a class with 76 varaibles). If what I compare is not equal (i.e. not duplicate I move the index up level and continue to the next, so on. On my travels if I find a duplicate element, i do the addition and remove, move the index back one and start until I reach the end.

im getting confused with the fact, im not sure if i need 2 index running in j `posCheckOptions[0][j]` because j only goes to j+1 once say index m has looped all 348 elements. This may not be 348 if i delete 2....

any advice is really welcome :-)

Comment: Do you need to avoid duplicates in one list or over all lists?

Comment: It's unclear what you consider to be the duplicates. Please elaborate a bit on what data you have and what output you expect.

Comment: over all lists. so, ill iterate the all the lists (32 which is the number of stocks) and the each stock contains many option positions which can be displayed as 25, 100 and I would like to add the 100 to the 25, then delete the 100....

Comment: You should create a sample of your problem on another, simplified code  to make it clear what you're really trying to achieve.

Comment: Are you doing != on calculated doubles?

Answer (score 5):

Looks like your problem can be easily solved using [LINQ](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb397926.aspx). I'm gonna show it on simplified example, so you'll have to adjust it you your real one.

Assume we have a class names `Item` as following:

```
public class Item
{
    public int Key { get; set; }
    public int SubKey { get; set; }
    public int Quantity { get; set; }
}
```

And a list (`List<Item>`):

```
var items = new List<Item>() {
    new Item { Key = 1, SubKey = 1, Quantity = 100 },
    new Item { Key = 1, SubKey = 2, Quantity = 400 },
    new Item { Key = 2, SubKey = 1, Quantity = 60 },
    new Item { Key = 1, SubKey = 1, Quantity = 10 },
    new Item { Key = 2, SubKey = 1, Quantity = 30 },
    new Item { Key = 1, SubKey = 1, Quantity = 70 }
};
```

Now, we'd like to sum `Quantity` for elements with the same pair of `Key` and `SubKey` (what will also remove duplicates). There is [`GroupBy`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534304.aspx) method within LINQ, so let's use it:

```
var groupedItems = items.GroupBy(x => new { x.Key, x.SubKey })
                        .Select(g => new Item {
                            Key = g.Key.Key,
                            SubKey = g.Key.SubKey,
                            Quantity = g.Sum(x => x.Quantity)
                        }).ToList();
```

As a result, we have a new `List<Item>` with only one element for every `Key`/`SubKey` pair and `Quantity` which is a sum of `Quantit`ies for items with that key pair.

Can it be expanded for `<List<List<Item>>` as an input and output? Sure it can.

Source nested `Item`s collection:

```
var nestedItems = new List<List<Item>>() {
    new List<Item>() {
        new Item { Key = 1, SubKey = 1, Quantity = 100 },
        new Item { Key = 1, SubKey = 2, Quantity = 400 },
        new Item { Key = 2, SubKey = 1, Quantity = 60 },
        new Item { Key = 1, SubKey = 1, Quantity = 10 },
        new Item { Key = 2, SubKey = 1, Quantity = 30 },
        new Item { Key = 1, SubKey = 1, Quantity = 70 }
    },
    new List<Item>() {
        new Item { Key = 1, SubKey = 1, Quantity = 100 },
        new Item { Key = 1, SubKey = 2, Quantity = 400 },
        new Item { Key = 2, SubKey = 1, Quantity = 60 },
        new Item { Key = 1, SubKey = 1, Quantity = 10 },
        new Item { Key = 2, SubKey = 1, Quantity = 30 },
        new Item { Key = 1, SubKey = 1, Quantity = 70 }
    },
    new List<Item>() {
        new Item { Key = 1, SubKey = 1, Quantity = 100 },
        new Item { Key = 1, SubKey = 2, Quantity = 400 },
        new Item { Key = 2, SubKey = 1, Quantity = 60 },
        new Item { Key = 1, SubKey = 1, Quantity = 10 },
        new Item { Key = 2, SubKey = 1, Quantity = 30 },
        new Item { Key = 1, SubKey = 1, Quantity = 70 }
    }
};
```

And the query:

```
var nestedGroupedItems = nestedItems.Select(x => x.GroupBy(y => new {y.Key, y.SubKey })
                                                  .Select(g => new Item {
                                                      Key = g.Key.Key,
                                                      SubKey = g.Key.SubKey,
                                                      Quantity = g.Sum(y => y.Quantity)
                                                  }).ToList()).ToList();
```

Comment: Thanks - I knew there was a way to do it with GroupBy and Sum, but I haven't got VS nearby to test.

Comment: @MarcinJuraszek, will try and implement this query and see if It works. Many Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest to do the following:

1. Implement the `IComparable` interface to the type of which the objects in the lists are. This way you can store the comparison logic inside the type itself.
2. Create a list of this type (just like the lists in `posCheckOptions`). Lets call it `bigList`
3. iterarte over all lists in `posCheckOptions`
4. iterate over each item in the contained list and check if the item is contained in `bigList`. If it is, delete it from the current inner list. If not add it to `bigList`

Answer (score -1):

I'm making some assumptions about the Type that contains your stock information, feel free to adjust as necessary. What you can do is create a dictionary mapping stock names to the stock objects. Update the object in the dictionary if it exists, or add it to the dictionary.

```
var allStock = mylist.SelectMany(l => l.Select(inner => inner));
var lookup = new Dictionary<string, Stock>();
foreach (var stock in allStock)
{
    if (!lookup.ContainsKey(stock.Name)) {
        lookup.Add(stock.Name, stock);
        continue;
    }
    lookup[stock.Name].Quantity += stock.Quantity;
}
```

Now you have a dictionary mapping the names of stock to the actual stock. Just iterate over the values to get a list back out if that's what you need.

Comment: Why the downvote? Feedback appreciated if this is wrong somehow.